# Validate a value of input parameter in the most concise way in Java

Tags: java, validation

Let's imagine a validation method call like this:

```
validate(foo, "foo");
```

where the second argument is the name of the variable provided in order to compose a meaningful exception message when the `foo` is `null`.

Is it possible in Java to retrieve the name of the provided value at runtime to avoid passing the name of the argument and make the method call look like in the following example?

```
validate(foo);
```

Comment: Nope; in any case argument names do no necessarily suvive the compilation proccess

Comment: The solution mentioned in your question is actually in use in some ways by a library developed by `Google`, especially for `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

> Update

I am assuming from the question that you are looking for the name of `argument` passed to that `method`, rather than name of `parameter` received by the method.

As the `object` passed could be `null` so there can be no information sent to the method in case of `argument`.

As the reference variable is just name carrying the address to actual `Object`. I don't think `JVM` cares about the `argument` name.

And there would be time when you send an `Object` like this `methodName(new Object())`. In this scenario there is no `argument` name But only the address of the `Object` passed to the `methodName`.

So given below code gives you some option ways to meet your requirement.

The solution mentioned in your question is actually in use in some ways by a library developed by `Google`, especially for `NullPointerException`

```
public class TestDriveException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyItem myItem = null;
        validate(myItem);


    }

    public static void validate(MyItem myItem) {
        if (myItem == null) {
            throw new MyArgumentException("myItem is null");
        }
    }


    private class MyItem {

        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private static class MyArgumentException extends NullPointerException {

        public MyArgumentException(String s) {
            super(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this can be done, or I am not sure about the argument as its just a name holding the address of the `Object`. For any sort of information to be passed from the `Object`, it has to be `non null`.

the other thing which you have suggested in the question can be used as well,

```
public static void validate(MyItem myItem, String argumentValue) {
    if (myItem == null) {
        throw new MyArgumentException(argumentValue+" is null");
    }
}
```